# How to display HTML same page title for all other html pages

Tags: html, css

I want to make number of HTML pages, where if I changed my title in main page it needs be changed in other pages too. how can I do that? Should I use Template inheritance?

I have 3 different html pages

> index.html
>   about.html
>   contact.html

Now if I changed Title of main.html then, the changed title must reflected on other 3 pages too. So I dont have to change title every single time.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>hello HTML</h1>
<p>learing HTML.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

about.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ABOUT ME</h1>
<h1>MY NAME IS TROJAN</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

and contact.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>contact ME</h1>
<h1>TROJAN@mymail.com</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must use other technologies like: ASPX using masterpage, ASP NET MVC, JQuery, AngularJS... and so on. You can't do only with html or css.

Comment: @bruce182 I wouldn't recommend asp, it's pretty much a dead language, use PHP or node.js

Comment: @bruce182  Actually I am Using python flask framework for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User jquery or script to add your page title on document ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'My Title';
    });

</script>
```

Or change your html files to php files and use global header for all pages.

Comment: i added this without script tag in m main.js file, And it works!!

Comment: this solution won't work without jquery and to add a resource heavy thing like jquery just for page titles seems redudant when pure js is perfectly fine .. reinder's answer is the better :)

Comment: This way you still have to change the title in all the files; it's just moved to javascript. Make your sample use an external JS file and it should work

Answer (score 4):

If you really need to stick with (static) HTML pages, you can only get this working using a single javascript file that is included on all HTML pages. In that file, you can set the title:

```
document.title = 'This is our new title';
```

Another option would be to use a server side language like PHP, ASP.NET, Java etc...

Comment: How can I do that In python??

Answer (score 1):

With JS you can also add id-"title" to html elements, that should have the same content and then:

```
const variable = "some string"
document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = `Your title here is able to also contains some ${variable}`;
```

Ofc. You will need to link that file.js in every file.html

Comment: You could also just do `document.title = "WHATEVER"` - no need to use an ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pure HTML, you must change the title of every file. Also you can create a script with python or any other scripting language to change it automatically, of course it's more work but worth it if you will develop a lot of sites.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do this in HTML, but you should do it in PHP. Change your file names to .php instead of .html then create a file named title.php

Inside this title.php file, you can create a variable:

```
<?php
    $title = “cool title”;
?>
```

Then echo it inside your `<title>` tags in your `index.php` file:

```
<head>
   <title><?php echo $title;?></title>
</head>
```

You will of course need to include this file in your index page:

```
<?php include "title.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I am using flask python

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs obviously just a syntax mistake. Feel free to correct next time. Takes less time than leaving a comment

Comment: @Niranjankulkarni that should be in your question; that’s pretty important information... You can apply this in any server side language. The answer is the same for all languages. Just create a variable and call it in your title tag

Comment: @ATomCalledStu Okay I will try that

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs because I forgot I didn’t have to :)